# Testing Pillow Image against Tensorflow model created from MNIST?

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, python-imaging-library

I went through the basic example on [MNIST For ML Beginners](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/beginners), and they've created a simple digit classifier from the MNIST database which is pretty cool.

The tutorial code they have is [mnist_softmax.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.4/tensorflow/examples/tutorials/mnist/mnist_softmax.py), but they use the classifier against their own test images. I want to try it on my own image loaded from Pillow.

Here is the part I've modified:

```
  from PIL import Image

  # Test trained model
  img = Image.open("09.png").convert('L')
  data = np.ndarray.flatten(np.array(img))
  result = sess.run(tf.argmax(y,1), feed_dict={x: [data]})
  print (' '.join(map(str,result)))
```

But this errors with:

```
ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (1, 1568) for Tensor u'Placeholder:0', which has shape '(?, 784)'
```

The images I'm using are 28x28:

[image]

[image]

As `9` and `14` respectively.

I might be misunderstanding how the classifier works since I've just started to read a few tutorials on the subject of Machine Learning. My question is how can I load these images from Pillow into the classifier, and have the classifier determine the correct digits?

---

**EDIT:** 
Based on @sascha's comments, I've updated the code, but am getting incorrect results. I tried cleaning up the `9` image:

[image]

But now the result is either `7` or `3`.

Comment: **Hint**: ```2352=28*28*3```. You somehow are using 3-channels (as in RGB). Force BW or Grayscale (1 bit vs. e.g. 8 bit) 1-channel reading.

Comment: @sascha Thanks for your hint. I've converted to grayscale using Pillow's `convert('LA')` and now I'm getting the error about `(1, 1568)`. I've modified my question to reflect this change.

Comment: @sascha Sorry, I messed up again. I added alpha when I shouldn't have. Removing that and I do get an output, but the `9` comes out as `7`. Is there a way to make it more accurate?

Comment: (Yes it's L**A** and it's wrong). A 9 becoming a 7 makes no sense. Open up the file in an image-editor and compare.

Comment: @sascha I opened up GIMP and tried to clean the image. The `9` is all either white pixels or black pixels. But running the program prints out `7` or `3` now. I also added my cleaned up image in my post, if that helps.

Comment: So you are saying: my classification-code i copied and used on my own data made an error? Yeah... sure... why not... That's completely irrelevant to this question (asking how to use my own images in terms of IO/array-shapes). That's also not a scientific evaluation. How is the accuracy? Are all classifications wrong? and so on... If your able to formulate a nice question after scientific eval, you can do that. But expect some downvotes when just linking to external code, which was not even written by you.

Comment: @sascha I'm not saying that the code or classification is wrong... Only that the result I'm seeing is wrong, and I don't know why. Probably due to my lack of knowledge of the ML subject; I've only started the tutorial, but I learn best when I can apply it to a small practical example (in this case to the few images I've generated). Hence why I modified the original code from the tutorial. I don't quite understand the hostility, but I guess nowadays SO isn't meant for those who are just learning and have a not-so-well-informed question to ask.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you have figured out the shape mismatch issue by converting your image to 1 channel. Now the problem is that your test prediction is wrong. So this explains that your ML model has failed for that test case.

Always calculate train and test accuracy to analyze the model performance and to know what problem your model is facing.

So look for solutions on how you can improve your model. Try Convolutional Neural Network, increase the number of layers, ensembling etc.

Check [this](https://www.kaggle.com/jananesekaran/99-45-cnn-batchnorm-ensembling) link where I have written a simple CNN model for digit recognition which has a 99.45 accuracy.

Refer to other kernels in Kaggle to know more about different approaches to the same problem.

Hope this helps!